# SQLite CASE, SUM and COUNT

Tags: android, sqlite, expandablelistview, android-sqlite

I am making a checklist app as a learning exercise.  The basics are working well, now I'm trying to add some bells and whistles.

When I sort my list by categories (in an `expandablelistview`), if all of the contents of the category are checked then the category group view should be checked.

I keep the flag for whether or not an individual list item is checked in the table containing the particular lists items.  I use a simple 1/0 flag to indicate checked or not checked.  My idea to implement my feature is to use something like this in my query to find out if all items are checked:

```
CASE WHEN sum(list_items.checked) = count(list_items.checked) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS 'groupchecked'
```

Thinking that if they are all checked (1) then the sum of them all should be equal to the count of them all... however, when I insert that code into my query, anything with more than one item per category does not show up.  I'm sure this problem is due to my lack of familiarity with SQLite but I cannot seem to figure out the proper way to make this work.

My current attempt at fetching my group cursor with the checked flag:

```
public Cursor fetchGroup(String group, long list) {
    String query = "SELECT DISTINCT "
            + group
            + " AS _id, CASE WHEN sum(list_items.checked) = count(list_items.checked) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS groupchecked FROM "
            + LISTITEM_TABLE
            + " JOIN "
            + ITEM_TABLE
            + " ON list_items.item_id=items._id WHERE list_items.list_id = "
            + list;
    return mDb.rawQuery(query, null);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
create table FOO(grp text, subgroup text, checked int)

insert into FOO(grp, subgroup, checked)
select 'feline','lion',1
union
select 'feline','tiger',0
union
select 'canine','dog',1
union
select 'canine','wolf',1


select grp, sum(checked) as checkedSum, count(checked) as checkedCount
from foo
group by grp
```

Now make an inline view:

```
select X.grp
from
(
select grp, sum(checked) as checkedSum, count(checked) as checkedCount
from foo
group by grp

) X

where checkedSum=checkedCount
```